# access private member data in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

In class A, I defined a private member data `char * d;`.

And also in class A, I am overloading operator= that takes a `const A &other` parameter and do assignment.

At this time when I am overloading operator=, I realized that my Visual Studio C++ doesn't give me an alert when I am trying to write something like `d = *other.d`.

So I am here to ask why I am allowed to do this? I haven't run this program yet but just curious why I didn't receive an alert for this line. In my mind private data members can only be accessed by getters.

So am I wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access restrictions operate by *class*, not by *instance* - `class A` methods can access private data for any instance of the class, not just `this`.

Comment: any standard documents on this problem?

Comment: Any standard book on C++ should explain this. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/